# Counting number of records that where date is in date range?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like below:

```
{startDate: ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z"), endDate: ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z")},
{startDate: ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z"), endDate: ISODate("2016-01-08T00:00:00Z")},
{startDate: ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z"), endDate: ISODate("2016-01-08T00:00:00Z")},
{startDate: ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z"), endDate: ISODate("2016-01-10T00:00:00Z")},
{startDate: ISODate("2016-01-07T00:00:00Z"), endDate: ISODate("2016-01-10T00:00:00Z")}
```

I would like to return a record for every date between the minimum `startDate` and the maximum `endDate`.  Along with each of these records I would like to return a count of the number of records where the `startDate` and `endDate` contain this date.

So for my above example the min `startDate` is `1/2/2016` and the max `endDate` is `1/10/2016` so I would like to return all dates between those two along with the counts.  See desired output below:

```
{date: ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z"), count: 2}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00Z"), count: 2}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"), count: 2}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z"), count: 4}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-06T00:00:00Z"), count: 3}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-07T00:00:00Z"), count: 4}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-08T00:00:00Z"), count: 4}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-09T00:00:00Z"), count: 2}
{date: ISODate("2016-01-010T00:00:00Z"), count: 2}
```

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense and I can try to explain in more detail.

I am able to do this using a loop like below:

```
var startDate = ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z")
var endDate = ISODate("2016-02-10T00:00:00Z")
while(startDate < endDate){
  var counts = db.data.find(
      {
        startDate: {$lte: startDate},
        endDate: {$gte: startDate}
      }
    ).count()
  print(startDate, counts)
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
}
```

But i'm wondering if there is a way to do this using the aggregation framework?  I come from a mostly SQL background where looping to get data is often a bad idea.  Does this same rule apply for MongoDB?  Should I be concerned about using looping here and try to use the aggregation framework or is this a valid solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is mapReduce. This is because you can loop values in between "startDate" and "endDate" within each document and emit for each day ( or other required interval ) between those values. Then it is just a matter of accumulating per emitted date key from all data:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        for( var d = this.startDate.valueOf(); d <= this.endDate.valueOf(); d += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) {
            emit(new Date(d), 1)
        }
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

This produces results like this:

```js
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-06T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 3
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-07T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-08T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-09T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-10T00:00:00Z"),
                        "value" : 2
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 35,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 5,
                "emit" : 25,
                "reduce" : 9,
                "output" : 9
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Your dates are rounded to a day in the sample, but if they were not in real data then it is just a simple matter of date math to be applied in order to round per interval.

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb aggregate framework there are stages instead of loop. It is a pipeline and it goes through each stage until it reaches the last stage specified. That is why you see a [] when using aggregate framework. there are several stages, to name a few (match, group and project). Take a look at their document it is quite simple. anyways that was very brief. As for your question here is my proposition:

I have not tried this. If you can try this and let me know if it works:

First you only keep those with dates in the range you desire using $match. Then follow that with the $group stage.
Example:

```
db.collection.aggregate{
    [
         {$match: {
             $and : [
                   {startDate: {$gte:ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z")}, 
                   {endDate: {$lte:ISODate("2016-02-10T00:00:00Z")}

                    ]
         },

         {$group:
             {_id: {startDate:"$startDate",endDate:"$endDate"},
              count:{$sum:1}
             }
          }
    ]
 }
```

If you want to just group using startDate as in you example replace

```
_id: {startDate:"$startDate",endDate:"$endDate"
```

with this:

```
_id: "$startDate"
```

I hope that helps

Comment: This is related but doesn't quite return the data I need.  Basically it returns a distinct start/end pair and how many other records have that start/end pair.  Again - similar to what I need but not quite the same.